# How to analyse wireless network problems?

Tags: networking, wifi

One of my Linux boxes, having a wireless NIC, connects to a remote machine and suddenly started disconnecting. Sometimes this wireless device disconnect after an hour, sometimes after 10 hours or sometimes after 27 hours but *I have to keep this machine running for at least 5 consecutive days without interruption.*

This Wi-Fi stack connects to a 802.1x WPA2 enterprise and the Access Point is just three (3) feet away from the machine (running in stationary mode).

Nothing relevant to Network seems to be logged in dmesg, syslog, klog or any other /var/log.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: 3 feet from the access point?  Why not plug it into the access point or add a hub to the access point if it has no free RJ45 ports. Which distro/kernel are you running on?

Comment: Is your Linux machine still running?

Comment: @Fabby its Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @danielAzuelos yes. Its still up and running but with Network interrupted though it auto connects after a while.

Comment: I solve such problems with scripts doing automatical re-initialization of the interface if there is no ping reply. As the last resort, you can go even until kernel module reload. It is not beautiful, but it is rock solid.

Comment: @peterh surely it's a last resort but I want uninterrupted. If Network disconnect then vmware session also get dropped

Comment: @SHW Not surely, there is no vmware in your question. Probably there are workarounds for that. The simplest would be to bridge the wlan0 with a fake interface what the vmware is using. If the wlan0 goes down, the vmware won't see that. It will see a packet loss, but if the cable reset happens enough quickly, it won't be a problem.

Comment: Did you check the AP log for possible errors on keys renewal?

Comment: Are there any other uses of your AP? Did you check it with its ARP table?

Comment: @danielAzuelos I don't think there is any problem with AP.  as I have connected 5 machine to same AP and all of 5 machines disconnect at random times.

Comment: Please add in your OQ what is your AP, and which other systems are connected to it.

Comment: "Nothing relevant to Network seems to be logged": this is very odd, because `wpa_supplicant` logs disconnects/disassociations, and I've seen messages every time in my logs. Please edit question and indicate *how you know* that it is disconnected (application fail? ping fail? something else?). Also, use `iw`, `ip` and `wpa_cli` to inspect the WLAN/interface/WPA state after a disconnection occurs.

Comment: If it's Ubuntu, please go [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and post the output link into your question here.  *Please do not cross-post* as most of us are on both sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the client is only three feet (1m) away from the AP.
One option would be simply to connect the two with a network cable and sidestep the entire wireless dropouts problem entirely.

Comment: That would be very weird solution. I am very much concern about the reason behind disconnection. I kept this machine so close to nullify the strength problem. Strength of this AP noted at Machine was above 60%

Comment: Why waste time trying to solve an issue that can be easily side-stepped?

Comment: OK. This can be side-stepped for machine? But what about mobile, roaming laptops?

Comment: You haven't asked about a mobile roaming laptop. You described a fixed machine 1m away from its AP that you needed to keep connected for a minimum of five days

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is the usual wireless network problem. Neither a typical Linux one nor of any AP OS.

Start analysing your wireless environment with a tool permitting to identify and timestamp the interference problems inside the 2 WLAN band (2.4 GHz, 5 GHz) and with Bluetooth and wireless phones (1.8 - 1.9 GHz).

As good starting points I suggest you to look at:

https://pentestmag.com/wifi-scanning-tools-on-ubuntu-14-04/

or:

https://istumbler.net/

I used professionnaly for years with great success.

Comment: I think it is more likely a driver problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Which driver is it?

Comment: It could be driver issue but I need to be much sure. And question is How?  Underlying driver is RTL8821AE